# How to implement tooltip with django form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, tooltip, django-crispy-forms

I have a model form based on this model:

```
class MyModel(TimeStampedModel):
    MY_CHOICES = [tuple([x,x]) for x in range(1,8)]
    p1 = models.IntegerField("P1", default='1', help_text='text1')
    p2 = models.IntegerField("P2", default='1', help_text='text2')
    Parent = models.ForeignKey(ParentModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The form itself looks like:

```
class MyModelForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_id = 'id-CaseForm'
        self.helper.form_class = 'blueForms'
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.help_text_inline = False
        self.helper.form_show_labels = False
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Row(Field(PrependedText('p1', ‘field_label1’,  wrapper_class='col-12 col-lg-6 pe-0 stretchprepend'))),
          Row(Field(PrependedText('p2’, ‘field_label2’,  wrapper_class='col-12 col-lg-6 pe-0 stretchprepend’))))

        CHOICES = [tuple([x,x]) for x in range(1,8)]
        p1 = IntegerField( label='field_label1', widget=Select(choices=CHOICES))
        p2 = IntegerField( label='field_label2’, widget=Select(choices=CHOICES))

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['p1', 'p2’,]
```

And this is displayed as a crispy form in the template:

```
{% crispy MyModelForm  %}
```

I want the user to see some help text when they hover over the fields. This help text could be the help_text from the model, or I am happy to put it somewhere else (although it should go in either the model or the form, not in the template). Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default html tooltip is available by defining `title` attribute on the `Field`. Help texts and other attributes of fields can be accessed from `self.base_fields`

For your case it will be:

```
self.helper.layout = Layout(
     Row(Field(
          PrependedText('p1', ‘field_label1’,wrapper_class='col-12 col-lg-6 pe-0 stretchprepend'),

          title=self.base_fields['p1'].help_text   # tooltip content
        ),
     )),
```

If you're using Bootstrap - nicer tooltip is available by:

**Bootstrap 5**

```
Field('field_name',
      title=self.base_fields['field_name'].help_text,
      data_bs_toggle='tooltip', 
      data_bs_placement='top')
```

And in the template:

```
<script>
  $('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
</script>
```

**Bootstrap 4**

```
Field('field_name',
      title=self.base_fields['field_name'].help_text,
      data_toggle='tooltip', 
      data_placement='top')
```

And in the template:

```
<script>
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
</script>
```

Comment: I can get a string to display if I enter it in the form  e.g.     Row(Field(PrependedText('p1', 'Delusions',  wrapper_class='col-12 col-lg-6 pe-0 stretchprepend')),
                title= 'test1', 
                data_bs_toggle='tooltip', 
                data_bs_placement='top'
            ),  But the help_text in the model doesn't seem to display?

Comment: @RobMcC `self.base_fields['p1'].help_text` should work. Double check if your field `p1` indeed has `help_text` defined

Comment: Thanks , where should it be defined - in the model as I have done in the example, or somewhere else?

Comment: @RobMcC, As in your example - `p1 = models.IntegerField("P1", default='1', help_text='text1')` this model is available inside `MyModelForm` in `self.base_fields['p1']`.

Comment: For some reason it isnt - if I check: print(self.base_fields['p1'].help_text) it just outputs an empty string (and I have made the migrations with the help text present)

Comment: print(inspect.getmembers(self.base_fields['p1'])) shows ('help_text', '')

Comment: @RobMcC. Noticed that you redefined those fields inside form. Remove `p1` and `p2` from the form itself. You don't need to define them there - they are taken from model via `Meta.model` and `Meta.fields`